# django custom user model need password2 for login form

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

i have custome user model  and login form to log in user but in form.is_valid() i have error:

password2

This field is required.

my user model:

```
class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email,username,password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('لطفا ایمیل را وارد کنید')
        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email,username, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_admin= True
        user.is_active=True
        user.is_staff=True
        user.is_superuser=True
        user.save()
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
class User(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100 , null=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, verbose_name="موبایل")
    email = models.CharField(max_length=180, verbose_name='ایمیل', unique=True, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    type = models.ForeignKey("userType.mUsertype", on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="نوع کاربری", null=True)
    addressmain = models.TextField(verbose_name="آدرس")
    website = models.CharField(max_length=100 , null=True)
    logo_url = models.CharField(max_length=100 , null=True)
    facebook_id = models.CharField(max_length=100 , null=True)
    instagram_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    telegram_id = models.CharField(max_length=100 , null=True)
    whatsapp_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, verbose_name="واتس آپ")
    twitter_id = models.CharField(max_length=100 , null=True)
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name="توضیحات")
    plan_expiry_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    plan_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100 , null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100 , null=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
    objects = MyAccountManager()
    def tokens(self):
        return 'token'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username.__str__()
```

my form:

```
class SigninForm(UserCreationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SigninForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        widgets={
            'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'ایمیل'}),
            'password1': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'پسورد'}),
        }
        fields = ("email","password1")


class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password1'].widget = forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'پسورد'})
        self.fields['password2'].widget = forms.PasswordInput(
            attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'تکرار پسورد'})
    class Meta:
        model = User
        widgets={
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'نام'}),
            'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'ایمیل'}),
            # 'password1': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'پسورد'}),
            # 'password2': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'تکرار پسورد'}),
        }
        fields = ("username","email","password1","password2","type")
```

my form in html and this is for login form:

```
                        <form  method="post">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {{ formsignin.email| add_class:"form-control" }}
                            {% if formsignin.email.errors %}
                                <div class="errors">
                                    {% for error in  formlogin.username.errors%}
                                        <p>{{ error }}</p>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            {% endif %}
                            {{ formsignin.password1| add_class:"form-control" }}
                            {% if formsignin.password1.errors %}
                                <div class="errors">
                                    {% for error in  formlogin.password.errors%}
                                        <p>{{ error }}</p>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            {% endif %}
                            <button class="btn btn-info" name='submit' type="submit" value='sign_in'>ورود</button>
                        </form>
```

and my view:

```
def signin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST)
        if request.POST.get('submit') == 'sign_in':
            form = SigninForm(request.POST)
            print(form.errors)
            if form.is_valid:
                email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
                password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
                user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
                if user is not None:
                    login(request,user)
                    return redirect('home')
                else:
                    messages.info(request,"نام کاربری یا رمز عبور اشتباه است")
            else:
                messages.info(request, "form is not true")
        elif request.POST.get('submit') == 'sign_up':
            print(request.POST)
            username = request.POST['username']
            email = request.POST['email']
            type = request.POST['type']
            password1 = request.POST['password1']
            password2 = request.POST['password2']
            myuser = User.objects.create_user(email,username,password1)
            myuser.save()
            messages.info(request, "ثبت نام شما با موفقیت ثبت شد")

    formsignin = SigninForm()
    formsignup = SignupForm()
    return render(request, "login.html", {'formsignin':formsignin,'formsignup':formsignup})
```

if i remove if form.is_valide() i have error for cleaned_data but the user save and all thing is work whats the problem!?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can delete field by built-in del method

```
class SigninForm(UserCreationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        del self.fields['password2']
```